# Parentheses around Whole Expression vs Leaving out Exponents

Tags: exponentiation, volume, unit-of-measure

What is the difference between:

```
5 cm^3
```

and

```
(5 cm)^3
```

Is there any difference in the sum of this equation?
If not, can this be applied to any other equation and result in a change of the answer, or is it just a difference in syntax?

Comment: Completely different.  The first is five cubic centimeters.  The second is a weird thing, possilbly meaning a cube 5 centimeters on a side, whose volume would then be $125\mathrm{  cm}^3$

Comment: Completely different.  THe first is 5 cubic centimers.  Take five dice and put the on the table.  The second 5 centimeters cubed.  Build a cube that is 5 cm by 5 cm by 5cm.  The whole thing will be a cube that has a volume of 125 cubic centimeters.

Comment: Without the parentheses, the exponent is essentially a part of the unit symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\left(5\ \mathrm{cm}\right)^3 = 5^3\ \mathrm{cm}^3 = 125\ \mathrm{cm}^3$ is the volume of a cube with a side $5$ centimeters.

$5\ \mathrm{cm}^3$ is a total volume of $5$ cubic centimeters, you need $25$ of those to equate to the previous item

Answer (score 3):

$5 cm^3$ vs $(5 cm)^3$: One is five cubic centimeters.  The other is 5 centimeters cubed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

$$(5 cm)^3 = 5^3 cm^3 = 125 cm^3\ne 5cm^3 $$

$(5 cm)^3$ is larger than $5cm^3$ by $25$ times.

$(5 cm)^3$ is the volume of a cube with $5 cm$ on each side.

$5 cm^3$ is the volume of a cuboid with sides $1cm, 1 cm $, and $5 cm$.

Comment: "5cm3  is the volume of a cuboid with sides 1cm,5cm, and 5cm" How is this true?

Comment: I made a mistake. meant to describe $1cm, 1cm, 5cm$. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.